# How to check value exists on sql table?

Tags: c#, sql

Hi at now im programming with C# and doing user signing up for their account. I already done with insert value to sql and now i want check the value is whether exists? 
Table detail:

```
Username              Password
Peter                 abc  
Hannah                abd 
John                  bdf
```

I am recommended a simple way to set Username as primary key and use try catch error to detect it. But i want to find the specific way to find my username exists. Tks

Comment: **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT**

Comment: Hm i understand but seems those answers are not for c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if the value exists before attempting an insert, you can write a SQL statement like this:

```
if not exists (select 1 from table where username=@username)
begin
     insert into ...
end
else
begin
    RAISERROR ('User already exists. Pick another one.', -- Message text.
           16, -- Severity.
           1 -- State.
           );
end
```

If the insert does not succeed because the username already exists, you can simply output the `Exception` message on the client side.

```
try
{
    //do the insert
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
   //Output ex.Message, it will say: User already exists. Pick another one.
}
```

A better approach IMO is to create the unique index on the username and let it fail due to the violation of the unique constraint. You can simply catch the Exception and display a user-friendly message.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to make the username the primary key. However, you *should* make it a unique index.

In any case, it's pretty simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from UserTable where Username = 'Peter'
```

... will return 1 (or more) if the username exists and 0 if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Username FROM mytable WHERE Username='Peter'
```

And then you can use code to determine if there is any row returned.

You can use this approach for login. But for signing up a new user, it's not guaranteed that nobody will take the username between the time you check and the time you INSERT the new record. So in any case, the try ... catch is unavoidable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
 `IF Exists(Select Top 1 * from Users where username = @userNameYouWantToCheck)
  Begin
... Do what you want to do if it exists...   
  END

 ELSE      
 BEGIN     
   ...catch error here...     
 END
```

`